# After moving a functional Drupal 7 site I am getting Jquery not defined

Tags: jquery, drupal

This is a server config issue, but mod rewrite is loading... Drupal is loading and url aliases are working but I'm getting jquery not defined which is leaving the pages without any CSS or theme, just white background with unformatted content.  I have also checked file permissions and they set correctly as is the .htaccess file, which was copied from the same environment as the rest of the site -- this unmodified code base was working on a different server, so I'm this is a server config issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: So the jquery file does not load? Have you checked that the path is correct? What file is throwing the error?

Comment: Use Firebug or some similar tool to see are all files loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a file permissions issue that was preventing drupal from reading the files.